# ABAP "SUPPLY": how to use a data-providing function module?

Tags: initialization, deadlock, abap

In the SUPPLY automatically-generated function modules, there can be seen the following comments:

```
* General Notes
* =============
* A common scenario for a supply method is to aquire key
* informations from the parameter <parent_element> and then
* to invoke a data provider.
* A free navigation thru the context, especially to nodes on
* the same or deeper hierachical level is strongly discouraged,
* because such a strategy may easily lead to unresolvable
* situations!!
*
** data declaration
*  DATA lt_nod TYPE wd_this->Elements_nod.
*  DATA ls_nod LIKE LINE OF lt_nod.
** @TODO compute values
** e.g. call a data providing **FuBa**
```

I understand the dangers of navigating through nodes that have an associated Supply Function but haven't been initialized yet - this basically leads to dead locks.

What i'd like to know is what's a **FuBa**, or **data provider** and how to use that - all the examples i've found only supply data for a node in a trivial manner, and don't tackle this problem.

Is that some way to register the nodes to be updated later... or... dunno ?

Comment: I've tried to answer the question regarding data providers - I'm not sure about the last sentence - what exactly is the question behind "dunno"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, **data provider** is not a technical term, it's just some coding that provides the data you want to add to the context. Whatever that may be depends on your application context - anything from a local or remote function module or method call, a call to your assistance class or even - if you really want to adopt bad coding habits - to a direct database access.

**FuBa** is an abbreviation of **Funktionsbaustein** = function module.

Comment: I think it should be rather called FuBaR.

Comment: @Jagger Please stay within the customer namespace - FuBaZ!

Comment: @vwegert Good point! However I will consider also the FuBaY option.